# How can I weight categorical variables to create a user preference score?

Tags: recommender-system, metric

I'm working on a collaborative filtering algorithm, possibly paired with content-based similarity, for pairing users with other users. I have plenty of data on users and their like events of other users as well as profile view timestamps. I need to create a "rating" score though, to get at the notion of strength of preference for a particular user before I can infer their preference for unseen users using similarity/nearest neighbors. The problem is that there are 4 different ways to like someone for this service, ranging from tinder-style indiscriminate swiping to thoroughly reading a profile and then finally swiping yes. My intuition tells me I should take these different like types into account in assigning a user preference rating, but all I could think to do was to do something like a linear combination of normalized numerical values (profile view length, view counts) plus the inverse-frequency of the like type, which would reduce the strength of the contribution of something like indiscriminate liking. I haven't tried it yet, but it just occurred to me to maybe figure out that kind of frequency-based weighting on a per user basis rather than across the sample of users.

Not all likes include profile views as well, so the lack of that field in the linear combination and a penalty for rapid swiping accords with my intuition that these likes should have little value in contributing to a user-on-user preference score.

However, I suspect there is some more rigorous statistical practice out there for dealing with this kind of situation, but Google-sensei has not turned up any results yet. Can someone please help steer me to a more rigorous methodology, or explain to me why my ideas suck (as they most likely do)?

Comment: Looks like you are asking for some kind of clustering of users?

Comment: No. What I'm looking for is a way to compute a "rating" the way a Netflix user might rate a movie. In this case, it is people rating other people through the form their interactions take.  There is the simple binary case of liked/didn't like, but it's not that simple, because there are different ways a user likes someone (Fast swiping. Barely pausing to look at photos or read profiles), and taking one's time scanning photos and reading being the extremes. To do collaborative filtering, I need some sort of preference metric. Liking is sparse, though, so I will need to use content too.

Comment: But, if "liking" takes many different forma, maybe it is multi-dimensional, so you need a vector score? In that case, ideas from multidimensional scaling (MDS).